# how to character put together as a string in C

Tags: c, encryption, character

Here is my code. i am trying to write a text file all characters (=p). But it writes just one character.

```
FILE *enc_vigenere = fopen(".../enc_vig.txt", "w");

unsigned int i, j, p = 0;         

for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(text);i++, j++){
    if(j>=strlen(key)) {
        j = 0;
    }
    if(text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z' ) {  

        p = 97+(((toupper(text[i])-65)+(toupper(key[j])-65))%26);

    }

    else if(text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') {

        p = 65+(((toupper(text[i])-65)+(toupper(key[j])-97))%26);
    }

    printf("%c", p);
    fprintf(enc_vigenere, "%c", p);
    fclose(enc_vigenere);
 }

}
```

Output is here:

```
Text you want to Encrypt : bahar
math
naahd
```

Result is true "naahd" but when i open text file i see just one character. **"n"** i couldnt find how fix it. Thank you.

Comment: you are ROCK! thanks. <3

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the code you compile ? `".../enc_vig.txt"` is fishy (3 dots instead of 2 dots).

Comment: it works, i just write it like that in here because too long :) of course not ... 3 dots :)

Comment: Hint: avoid "magic" numbers such as `65` and `97`. Instead use `'A'` and `'a'` etc. It's less error prone and easier to understand.

Comment: **Here is my code.** Where is it?

Comment: sorry i am new here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fclose(enc_vigenere);` needs to be outside the `for` loop.
2. This is not portable C. You cannot assume that `a` through to `z` appear in one block. (Ditto `A` to `Z`.) You also cannot assume that 65 is the value of `A`.

For (2) use `int islower(int c)` and `int isupper(int c)` instead. Those functions are portable.

Comment: thanks, i moved `fclose(enc_vigenere);` out of for loop and then works. Hmmm ok thank you.